# Blank Desktop (No Icons) after Windows Update

Tags: windows, windows-8

I have a windows 8.1 laptop.

When I start it, the desktop is black. There are no icons and I can't right click on the desktop. I can right click the taskbar, or I can do the windows button + r to get the run menu up.

If i go into safe mode, all the icons show up just fine. Except for when the computer originally starts in safe mode, a box pops up saying "Hard Error" and that's it.

I've tried doing sfc /scannow, only for it to say it found corrupted files but couldn't repair them.

I've tried running a DISM only to get it to say error 193.

I've tried running a system restore, only for it to say system restore couldn't be completed after the computer restarted.

I'm honestly not sure what to try next. Anybody have any ideas?

Comment: If `Ctrl + Alt + Del` is valid in your computer, try to open `Task manager` and run new task `explorer.exe`.

Comment: @DaiNguyen-Van, I ran it and it opened an explorer window.

Comment: Sorry you can kill `explorer.exe` process before run it as a new task. As I know, `explorer.exe` process handles icon display and right click handle. It might be explorer doesn't work correctly, this way is to reset it, then check right click on the desktop.